# Rustup update broke linker

Tags: rust, linker-errors, rustup

One day, I was installing cargo-binutils and llvm then I decided to update rustc and cargo.After I updated rustc and cargo with then command

```
rustup udpate
```

I can't compile any program anymore, it prints this

```
error: linker `link.exe` not found
  |
  = note: program not found

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that Visual Studio 2017 or later, or Build Tools for Visual Studio were installed with the Visual C++ option.
```

I tried uninstall cargo-binutils and llvm thinking it would solve the problem but it wouldn't.

I had compiled every programs fine before this happened. Could someone explains why this happened? Thanks in advance